# Earring, don't use is or are? Pronouns “it” or “they”

Tags: singular-vs-plural, pronouns, nouns

I know that sunglasses, scissors, pants are plural. How about earring? If it's a pair (both left and right are alike), do we say "I love them" or "I love it"?

I got a present from my friend who is a native speaker, in the gift card she wrote “I hope you like **it**”

So, how should I reply?

Comment: Sunglasses, scissors, and pants are attached to each other.  You can't have one sunglass or scissor or pant by itself without breaking something.  (You can have a glass, but this refers to a drinking cup, not spectacles.  A pant could also refer to breathing rather than trousers(US)/underwear(UK).)  This is not true of earrings.  They may be a pair, but they are 2 separate objects, much like shoes or gloves.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman note however one can have a singular “trouser leg”, of which there are two in a “pair of trousers”.

Comment: This is a perfect example of how language morphs, or changes. Technically, ***a pair*** of earrings is a singular item - ***a*** pair. Like a pair of shoes is one pair. No multiples there. But, as language changes, and perhaps we get lazy, that becomes plural. A pair of anything *ought* to be singular, but often (as here) it can be considered not. ***A gift***, though is always singular, and it's impossible to know whether your donor is referring to the pair, or the gift. My money's on the gift.

Answer (score 23):

One earring is singular. Two earrings are plural. There's no special case here like there is with scissors. Usually one would say "I hope you like them," unless only one earring was gifted. However, two earrings together can make up **a gift**, which is singular, and with this in mind one *can* also say "I hope you like it."

> - I got you a gift. I hope you like it.
> - I got you some earrings. I hope you like them.

As for how you should reply... well... you can rarely go wrong with a nice "thank you!"

Comment: In addition, the gift card is referring the "unopened" gift, which is singular. The fact that it contains a pair of earrings (plural) wouldn't be known until the gift is opened, so the card avoids giving any hints about what the gift is. (The same logic applies even if the gift isn't wrapped and it's immediately obvious that a pair of earrings is involved.)

Comment: A pair (of earrings) is a singular noun, hence "it" is correct

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg Whether to use singular or plural with collective nouns like "pair" is complicated, and in some cases varies between dialects - British English treats them as plural more often than American English. To my ear "I got you a pair of earrings. I hope you like them." sounds better than "I got you a pair of earrings. I hope you like it.".

Comment: @IMSoP I'm American and my ear agrees with you. Another example: "I got you a box of cookies, I hope you like them." "It" would refer to the container itself, not the contents.

Answer (score 2):

By using ***it*** what your friend meant was that she hoped you would like the ***present***.

Answer (score 1):

"I hope you like **it**" — referring to the (singular) gift. Because "it" also keeps the contents of the gift a surprise (or at least references that endearing cliché, in cases where the gift is known), this pronoun choice comes across as more playful, caring, thoughtful etc.

After receiving the gift, you open it and reveal: earrings (plural). Now you should use "they" to talk about both earrings and "it" to talk about just one of them.

> So, how should I reply?

The truly idiomatic reply would be "I love them". Probably every soap ever contains at least one gift-giving scene "I hope you like it"—"I looove them!"

Answer (score 0):

> So, how should I reply?

"Thank you for the lovely earrings!"
"It was a thoughtful gift!"